# How to add exposed form block to .tpl.php

Tags: theming

I've added this code to preprocess function but it dosen't work :
in preprocess :

```
//edit_search_api_views_fulltext is the form_id of exposed form block;
$vars['custom_search'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form("edit_search_api_views_fulltext"));
```

in tpl.php

```
print $custom_search;
```

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print an exposed block in tpl, right? I am using this in drupal 7

```
<?php 
  $block = block_load('views', '-exp-VIEWNAME-DISPLAYNAME'); 
  $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
  print $output; 
?>
```

for example

```
<?php
  $search_block = block_load('views', '-exp-cruise_package-page');
  $output =  drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($search_block)))); 
  print $output; 
?>
```